# Am i approaching this problem the correct way, ifelse after a group_by

Tags: r

My df is like this

```
Month<-c("May","May","May","May","May","May","May","May","June","June","June")
Manager<-c("Eric","Eric","Eric","Eric","Eric","Eric","Charlie","Charlie","Adam","Charlie","Adam")
`Order Type`<-c("Direct","Direct","Direct","Team Personal Use","Charity","Charity","Direct","Fatima","Fatima","Fatima","Direct")
`SVS ORD #`<-as.numeric(c("112231","112232","112233","112234","112235","112235","112236","112237","112238","112239","112240"))
Qty<-as.numeric(c("1","2","3","3","3","1","4","2","3","2","3"))

df <- data.frame(Month, Manager, `Order Type`, `SVS ORD #`, Qty)
```

What i want to do for each manager in each Month to check how much they ordered. However, this is complicated by the fact that if the order type is **Direct** or **Team Personal Use**, Remove duplicates of SVS ORD # and count the number of unique SVS ORD #. For rest, it should just take the first QTY value of the SVS Ord #.

My code is something like this.

```
df %>%
  group_by(Month,Manager) %>%
  mutate(`QTYMonthManager` = ifelse(`Order Type` == 'Direct' | `Order Type` == 'Team Personal Use',
                                         n_distinct(`SVS ORD #`),
                                         sum(Qty[!duplicated(`SVS ORD #`)])))
```

However, this is not giving me the correct answer at all. Any help is appreciated!

Desired Output

```
Month<-c("May","May","May","May","May","May","May","May","June","June","June")
Manager<-c("Eric","Eric","Eric","Eric","Eric","Eric","Charlie","Charlie","Adam","Charlie","Adam")
`Order Type`<-c("Direct","Direct","Direct","Team Personal Use","Charity","Charity","Direct","Fatima","Fatima","Fatima","Direct")
`SVS ORD #`<-as.numeric(c("112231","112232","112233","112234","112235","112235","112236","112237","112238","112239","112240"))
Qty<-as.numeric(c("1","2","3","3","3","3","4","2","3","2","3"))
**Answer** <-as.numeric(c("7","7","7","7","7","7","3","3","4","2","4"))
```

Comment: Your column names should be `check.names = FALSE` in `data.frame`

Comment: Please check if the expected output is correct

Comment: It should be because there are 4 Direct/Team Personal use SVS Ord # for Eric and then 3 QTY for Charity for Eric so 4+3=7 in the month of May. Charlie has 1 Direct SVS Ord and then 2 QTY for Fatima in the month of May so it should be 3 and so on

Comment: The length of `ifelse` should be same across the `test`, `yes` `no`.

Comment: Your conditions were not clear because in the code, there was no summing of the two

Comment: Sorry, yeah, that was what i was not getting, trying to add the two

Comment: That's what you did though Ronak and that's what i wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following function :

```
library(dplyr)
calculate_answer <- function(Order.Type, SVS.ORD.., Qty) {
   i <- Order.Type %in% c('Direct','Team Personal Use')
   n_distinct(SVS.ORD..[i]) + sum(Qty[!i][!duplicated(SVS.ORD..[!i])])
}
```

and apply it for each group.

```
df %>%
   group_by(Month, Manager) %>%
    mutate(Answer = calculate_answer(Order.Type, SVS.ORD.., Qty))

#  Month Manager Order.Type        SVS.ORD..   Qty Answer
#   <chr> <chr>   <chr>                 <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 May   Eric    Direct               112231     1      7
# 2 May   Eric    Direct               112232     2      7
# 3 May   Eric    Direct               112233     3      7
# 4 May   Eric    Team Personal Use    112234     3      7
# 5 May   Eric    Charity              112235     3      7
# 6 May   Eric    Charity              112235     1      7
# 7 May   Charlie Direct               112236     4      3
# 8 May   Charlie Fatima               112237     2      3
# 9 June  Adam    Fatima               112238     3      4
#10 June  Charlie Fatima               112239     2      2
#11 June  Adam    Direct               112240     3      4
```

Comment: I would never have thought of this approach this year at least. Thank you so much.